# eCommerce / Shop system with good support for GDPR requirements

Tags: e-commerce, shopify, webshop

I know [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/908181/can-you-help-me-with-my-gdpr-issue) and [that](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/367027/blacklist-gdpr) but I think my question is valid. Also I couldn't find another, more appropriate StackExchange community for my question.

My task is to replace our legacy webshop with a new one which makes compliance to the GDPR requirements as easy as possible. Until now, I haven't found a shop system with the following features:

- guest checkout
- explicit active consent for the different kinds of personal data
- support for parental consent
- software support for customers to see, edit, export and delete ALL their personal data

I imagine if those are fulfilled the company itself would have also made sure that it acts in a GDPR compliant way, so I don't mention this explicitly.